# Bashdb in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, bash, official-repositories

I cannot find [bashdb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) in Ubuntu (MATE) 20.04 repos, i.e apt returns nothing when searching for 'bashdb'. I'd rather avoid installing it from source. Do you know why it was not added to the repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bashdb` is not available in the Repos anymore.

You *could* install the `.deb` version still [available in the Universe Repo](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/bashdb/bashdb_4.2.0.8-1.1_all.deb) for Ubtunu 16.04, all its dependencies are fine with 20.04.
But it seems outdated.

I would go with the latest version, that is also provded as a `.deb` package on the [official download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashdb/files/).

Comment: I mean, it's great that you can get it as a .deb or .tar but this is a very useful (if not essential) tool. I don't understand why maintainers couldn't add it to repos. External debs are also not best way to install software from security perspective

Comment: I agree.  Why is this not in the repos??

Comment: Instead of asking why some *else* is not doing something about this, you or others who want this, could investigate and devote time to get it back In the process, you'll probably have a better appreciation of what is involved.